# Interpretation of discrepancies between contrasts comparisons in lmer and emmeans

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have the following model with 4 levels under the `Group` factor variable and 3 levels under `Cue_Type`.

```
contrasts(data$Cue_Type) <-contr.sdif(3) 

levels(data$Cue_Type) # angry, happy, square

[1] "angry"  "happy"  "square"


contrasts(data$Group) <-contr.sdif(4) 

levels(data$Group) 
[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"
```

```
summary(model1)

Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: RT ~ Group * Cue_Type + (1 + Cue_Type | Partno)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 43396.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.3082 -0.6940 -0.0873  0.6591  3.9750 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name            Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
 Partno   (Intercept)     0.01993  0.1412              
          Cue_Typehappy   0.01075  0.1037   -0.10      
          Cue_Typesquare  0.01198  0.1095   -0.03 -0.47
 Residual                 0.10201  0.3194              
Number of obs: 76629, groups:  Partno, 71

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error       df t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                6.03364    0.04270 67.02069 141.297 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GroupB                    -0.01352    0.05273 67.08740  -0.256               0.7985    
GroupC                    -0.04728    0.06186 66.93473  -0.764               0.4474    
GroupD                    -0.03171    0.05015 66.99277  -0.632               0.5293    
Cue_Type2-1               -0.08423    0.03254 67.69907  -2.589               0.0118 *  
Cue_Type3-2               -0.20410    0.03389 67.43201  -6.023         0.0000000795 ***
GroupB:Cue_Typehappy       0.07719    0.04035 67.57922   1.913               0.0600 .  
GroupC:Cue_Typehappy       0.02081    0.04695 66.60267   0.443               0.6591    
GroupD:Cue_Typehappy       0.04312    0.03816 67.34450   1.130               0.2624    
GroupB:Cue_Typesquare     -0.05290    0.04177 67.01643  -1.267               0.2097    
GroupC:Cue_Typesquare     -0.02915    0.04900 66.82395  -0.595               0.5538    
GroupD:Cue_Typesquare     -0.04498    0.03978 67.26217  -1.131               0.2621    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like to correct for multiple testing and explore the marginal significant effect I find on GroupB:Cue_Typehappy.

```
library(emmeans)
model1.lsm <- emmeans(model1, specs = pairwise~ Group*Cue_Type, type = "response",lmer.df = "satterthwaite", lmerTest.limit = 76629, adjust = "mvt") 



$emmeans
 Group    Cue_Type emmean     SE   D  f lower.CL upper.CL
 A        angry      6.16 0.0490 66.8     6.06     6.26
 B        angry      6.11 0.0357 68.0     6.04     6.18
 C        angry      6.11 0.0513 66.2     6.00     6.21
 D        angry      6.11 0.0301 66.4     6.05     6.17
 A        happy      6.07 0.0461 67.3     5.98     6.17
 B        happy      6.10 0.0333 66.8     6.04     6.17
 C        happy      6.04 0.0483 66.8     5.95     6.14
 D        happy      6.07 0.0284 67.1     6.01     6.13
 A        square     5.87 0.0455 67.1     5.78     5.96
 B        square     5.85 0.0329 67.0     5.78     5.91
 C        square     5.81 0.0477 67.0     5.71     5.90
 D        square     5.82 0.0280 67.0     5.77     5.88

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                    estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 A angry - B angry            0.04734 0.0607 67.2  0.780  0.9995 
 A angry - C angry            0.05143 0.0710 66.5  0.725  0.9997 
 A angry - D angry            0.04546 0.0575 66.7  0.790  0.9994 
 A angry - A happy            0.08423 0.0325 67.7  2.589  0.2430 
 A angry - B happy            0.05438 0.0593 81.2  0.918  0.9977 
 A angry - C happy            0.11486 0.0688 84.0  1.670  0.8281 
 A angry - D happy            0.08657 0.0566 79.0  1.529  0.8948 
 A angry - A square           0.28834 0.0341 66.8  8.445  <.0001 
 A angry - B square           0.31139 0.0590 82.8  5.276  <.0001 
 A angry - C square           0.34811 0.0684 86.3  5.092  0.0001 
 A angry - D square           0.33566 0.0564 80.2  5.947  <.0001 
 B angry - C angry            0.00409 0.0625 66.8  0.065  1.0000 
 B angry - D angry           -0.00188 0.0468 67.3 -0.040  1.0000 
 B angry - A happy            0.03689 0.0583 83.8  0.632  0.9999 
 B angry - B happy            0.00704 0.0239 67.3  0.295  1.0000 
 B angry - C happy            0.06751 0.0601 82.9  1.124  0.9876 
 B angry - D happy            0.03923 0.0456 84.2  0.860  0.9987 
 B angry - A square           0.24099 0.0578 85.8  4.167  0.0027 
 B angry - B square           0.26404 0.0251 67.4 10.532  <.0001 
 B angry - C square           0.30077 0.0596 85.1  5.049  0.0001 
 B angry - D square           0.28831 0.0454 86.1  6.351  <.0001 
 C angry - D angry           -0.00597 0.0595 66.3 -0.100  1.0000 
 C angry - A happy            0.03280 0.0690 83.7  0.476  1.0000 
 C angry - B happy            0.00295 0.0612 80.1  0.048  1.0000 
 C angry - C happy            0.06343 0.0338 65.6  1.874  0.7022 
 C angry - D happy            0.03514 0.0586 77.8  0.599  1.0000 
 C angry - A square           0.23690 0.0685 85.6  3.456  0.0273 
 C angry - B square           0.25996 0.0609 81.6  4.266  0.0021 
 C angry - C square           0.29668 0.0356 65.4  8.330  <.0001 
 C angry - D square           0.28422 0.0584 79.0  4.863  0.0002 
 D angry - A happy            0.03877 0.0551 81.0  0.704  0.9998 
 D angry - B happy            0.00892 0.0449 83.6  0.199  1.0000 
 D angry - C happy            0.06939 0.0569 80.0  1.220  0.9768 
 D angry - D happy            0.04111 0.0199 66.4  2.062  0.5712 
 D angry - A square           0.24287 0.0546 82.8  4.452  0.0011 
 D angry - B square           0.26593 0.0446 85.9  5.961  <.0001 
 D angry - C square           0.30265 0.0564 81.9  5.367  <.0001 
 D angry - D square           0.29019 0.0210 65.8 13.849  <.0001 
 A happy - B happy           -0.02985 0.0569 67.2 -0.525  1.0000 
 A happy - C happy            0.03062 0.0667 67.1  0.459  1.0000 
 A happy - D happy            0.00234 0.0541 67.2  0.043  1.0000 
 A happy - A square           0.20410 0.0339 67.4  6.023  <.0001 
 A happy - B square           0.22715 0.0566 85.2  4.011  0.0047 
 A happy - C square           0.26388 0.0663 87.8  3.980  0.0051 
 A happy - D square           0.25142 0.0539 82.6  4.662  0.0006 
 B happy - C happy            0.06047 0.0586 66.8  1.031  0.9936 
 B happy - D happy            0.03219 0.0437 66.9  0.736  0.9997 
 B happy - A square           0.23395 0.0564 85.3  4.151  0.0030 
 B happy - B square           0.25700 0.0244 66.2 10.527  <.0001 
 B happy - C square           0.29373 0.0581 84.5  5.052  0.0001 
 B happy - D square           0.28127 0.0435 86.7  6.466  <.0001 
 C happy - D happy           -0.02829 0.0560 66.9 -0.505  1.0000 
 C happy - A square           0.17348 0.0663 87.5  2.616  0.2248 
 C happy - B square           0.19653 0.0584 84.0  3.365  0.0353 
 C happy - C square           0.23326 0.0354 66.3  6.592  <.0001 
 C happy - D square           0.22080 0.0558 81.3  3.957  0.0057 
 D happy - A square           0.20176 0.0536 82.8  3.765  0.0107 
 D happy - B square           0.22482 0.0434 87.1  5.177  0.0001 
 D happy - C square           0.26154 0.0555 81.9  4.716  0.0004 
 D happy - D square           0.24908 0.0208 66.8 11.962  <.0001 
 A square - B square          0.02305 0.0561 67.1  0.411  1.0000 
 A square - C square          0.05978 0.0659 67.0  0.908  0.9979 
 A square - D square          0.04732 0.0534 67.1  0.886  0.9983 
 B square - C square          0.03673 0.0579 67.0  0.634  0.9999 
 B square - D square          0.02427 0.0432 67.0  0.562  1.0000 
 C square - D square         -0.01246 0.0553 67.0 -0.225  1.0000 

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
P value adjustment: mvt method for 66 tests
```

My confusion arises from the fact that the effects on contrast comparisons I set in the `model1` (plesae note that I change the baseline in `contr.sdif()` to run all possible combinations of contrasts) show different effects in terms of significance compared to the contrasts from `emmeans()`, so I am not sure how to approach that in terms of reporting and interpretation.

I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Please read the annotations below the comparisons output. The P values are adjusted for multiplicity,and there are a zillion tests!

Comment: I also suggest that you cut back the comparisons to the ones ou may actually need, e.g., `pairs(model1.lsm[[1]], simple = "each")`

Comment: @RussLenth thanks for the response. So the 'simple = "each"' does not show any significant group comparisons for each cue so I guess I should just report this marginal effect without further interpretation. So generally, how should interpretation be handled when accounting for multiplicity we find significant contrasts that we do not when examining the contrasts effects in the model? I am little bit confused on that..

Comment: The coefficients output gives only SOME of the comparisons, if that, and they are not adjusted for multiplicity. So trying to interpret coefficients is not all it's cracked up to be, especially in cases where there is more than one factor. I suggest going straight to the comparisons, which will be the same regardless of how you coded the contrasts. And I think you SHOULD report the comparisons, whether or not you think they are "significant." Let your reader see the effects and P values (suitably adjusted).

Comment: Thank you very much @RussLenth